# Permissions issue for google cloud build terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a terraform to create github repo connection to cloud build exactly like in [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/github/connect-repo-github?generation=2nd-gen#connecting_a_github_host_programmatically), the repository in the organization and I used separate account and from it created a person access token, but I noticed that without giving this account admin permission (even maintain is not enough), I would get an error in terraform:

```
 Error: Error waiting to create Repository: Error waiting for Creating Repository: Error code 9, message: the authorized user doesn't have the admin permission to repo
```

there is no mention of needing admin permissions and I'm wondering what's the reason to have it and why it doesn't work without it?

Comment: You need admin permission because the process will create, behind the scene, webhook on GitHub to call Cloud Build.